# How can I write a using a struct to a MTLBuffer?

Tags: swift, pointers, metal

I have an array of 3 MTLBuffers. They are created and then reused. They are managed with semaphores to avoid conflicts. I need to write to them using a struct I created. I'm having trouble binding to the MTLBuffer and assign my struct format to it. I'm converting this from OBJ-C to SWIFT. The OBJ-C code works. I'm getting an error in SWIFT "Cast from '(any MTLBuffer)?' to unrelated type 'AAPLUniforms' always fails" How can I do this?

The struct

```
typedef struct{
matrix_float4x4 mvpMatrix;
float pointSize;} AAPLUniforms;
```

I create the array of MTLBuffers here

```
/ Create and allocate the dynamic uniform buffer objects.
for i in 0..<AAPLMaxRenderBuffersInFlight {
  // Indicate shared storage so that both the  CPU can access the buffers
  let storageMode: MTLResourceOptions = .storageModeShared
  
  dynamicUniformBuffers[i] = device.makeBuffer(
    length: MemoryLayout<AAPLUniforms>.size,
    options: storageMode)
  
  dynamicUniformBuffers[i]?.label = String(format: "UniformBuffer%lu", i)
}
```

I'm getting an error "Cast from '(any MTLBuffer)?' to unrelated type 'AAPLUniforms' always fails" trying at bind the MTLBuffer to the struct type

```
  func updateState() {

var uniforms = dynamicUniformBuffers[currentBufferIndex] as? AAPLUniforms

uniforms?.pointSize = AAPLBodyPointSize
uniforms?.mvpMatrix = projectionMatrix!
}
```

The working OBJC code looks like this

```
- (void)updateState{
AAPLUniforms *uniforms = (AAPLUniforms *)_dynamicUniformBuffers[_currentBufferIndex].contents;
uniforms->pointSize = AAPLBodyPointSize;
uniforms->mvpMatrix = _projectionMatrix;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the pointer to the actual memory of the `MTLBuffer`'s contents.  You get that using its `contents()` method, which will return an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. You can then call its `bindMemory` method to bind (cast) it to `UnsafeMutablePointer<AAPLUniforms>`.  After that, you can use its `pointee` property to access your `AAPLUniforms` instance.

I think this should do what you want:

```swift
let uniformsPtr = dynamicUniformBuffers[currentBufferIndex]!.contents()
    .bindMemory(to: AAPLUniforms.self, capacity: 1)

uniformsPtr.pointee.pointSize = AAPLBodyPointSize
uniformsPtr.pointee.mvpMatrix = projectionMatrix!
```

Comment: Small change and it worked.

Comment: Fixed two errors and it worked. 1. needed  to unwrapped dynamicUniformBuffer 2. count changed to capacity. Changed line of code: let uniformsPtr = dynamicUniformBuffers[currentBufferIndex]!.contents()
      .bindMemory(to: AAPLUniforms.self, capacity: 1)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Good catch on the fixes.  I've updated my answer to include them.  I normally prefer to handle the `nil` case when I make Metal objects, so I hadn't noticed that `dynamicUniformsBuffers` contained optionals.

Comment: I posted a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985474/how-do-i-specify-a-deallocator-for-memory-allocated-with-mem-align-in-swift. Is this one you can help with?